# UIPickerView is not selecting the date in UITextField

Tags: swift, datepicker, uipickerview

I am new in swift. On executing this app login screen goes to sign in.On selecting "Already have account sign up".You get to sign up view. In the sign up trying to develop the picker view.These are two issues arise while developing picker view

1) picker view should be hidden on loading view controller .but picker view is visible as view controller appear?

2) In date of birth pickview when a done button on date picker view is selected the app crash .but it should display the corresponding date in a text field?

```
func showDatePicker(){
        //Formate Date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()


        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "donedatePicker")
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "cancelDatePicker")
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

        dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        dateTextField.inputView = datePicker

    }
    func donedatePicker(){

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        dateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    pickerView.delegate=self
    pickerView.dataSource=self
    genderTextField.inputView=pickerView

    showDatePicker()

}
```

How to avoid this crash. You can download the project from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a6Pmw2gVDwLP9grL8tG72NBx-tKwZozI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where did you call showDatePicker() method?

Comment: i have edited the question .in view did load

Comment: When do you want to show picker view?

Comment: to show gender male female

Comment: Do you want to show date picker on tap on UITextField?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss few things in view did load I had updated the code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.delegate=self
        pickerView.dataSource=self
        genderTextField.inputView = pickerView
        genderTextField.delegate = self
        dateTextField.delegate = self

    }
```

Assign the text field delegate and implement the function textFieldShouldBeginEditing function for showing the Date Picker

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag == 1 { //Date Text Field
            showDatePicker()
        }
        return true
    }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

I had assigned the tag value of Date Text Field from the storyboard and hide the picker view from the storyboard. It will solve your both points

Comment: genderTextField.delegate = self //Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'
        dateTextField.delegate = self . //Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'.........the last two lines of viewDidLoad is giving following error

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

Comment: include UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: How to make disappear the picker view when view controller is loaded

Comment: just hide them for now, from storyboard

Comment: Click on Storyboard-> Select ViewController Scenc -> Click on Picker view -> From right pannel select Attribute Inpector -> see there will be option of Hidden -> Click that checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        pickerView.delegate=self
        pickerView.dataSource=self
        genderTextField.inputView=pickerView

        showDatePicker()

    }
```

The mistake is here. When the view is load in `viewDidLoad`, date picker is show itself. So you must add a action for click to show you picker view and call it in there.

For example

```
@objc fileprivate func showIt(_ sender:UIButton){
   showDatePicker()
}
```

Also your action must be set wit #selector

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "donedatePicker")
```

changed to

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))
```

And for error #1 you must be make `firstResponder` `UITextField` somehow, you must resign it.

Can you add this function for textFieldDelegate.

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
       func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if textField.isFirstResponder{
                showDatePicker()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: how to make firstResponder UITextField to resign it?

Comment: `myTextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: genderTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        dateTextField.resignFirstResponder() ...i have placed these statements in view did load but error #1 still persists ..

Comment: Edited the answer again

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give delegate to UITextField i.e

dateTextField.delegate = self

and then you need to confirm with UITextFieldDelegate method with sign up class i.e

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       if textField ==  dateTextField {
          self.showDatePicker()
       }

}
```

Use this above code may it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you should b calling this `showDatePicker()` on a tap at date textfield.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    if startDateTxt == textField{
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDatePicker()), for: .valueChanged)
    }
 }
```

and for 2nd error:

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))
```